# get an error though proper initialized arraylist in java

Tags: java, arraylist

i want to passing value in arraylist, and initialized well. but there is an error -

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 0

I am trying hard, here is my code -

```
      public static void main(String[]args)
        {
            int n = 3;
            ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> graph = new ArrayList<>(n+2);
            for(int i=0; i < n+2 ; i++) {
                graph.add(new ArrayList<>(n+2));
            }
            graph.get(1).add(3,9);
            graph.get(2).add(3,1);
            graph.get(1).add(2,5);

            int s = 1, d = 3;
            System.out.println(dijkstra(s,d,graph));
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

The following line means adding `9` at index, `3`

```
graph.get(1).add(3,9);
```

However, `graph.get(1)` returns an `ArrayList<Integer>` which is empty. That's why you are getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 0
```

### Solution

Replace

```
graph.get(1).add(3,9);
```

with

```
graph.get(1).add(9);
```

which will add the element (e.g. `9` in this case) after the last index where an element has been added. In this case, `9` will be added at index, `0`.

### Update

Alternatively, you can initialize the inner list as follows:

```
for(int i=0; i < n+2 ; i++) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int j = 0; j< n+2; j++){
        list.add(0);
    }
    graph.add(list);
}
```

and then you can carry on as follows (the way you have already done):

```
graph.get(1).add(3,9);
graph.get(2).add(3,1);
graph.get(1).add(2,5);
```

### Update 2

Given below is the concise way based on [Andy Turner's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61956628/get-an-error-though-proper-initialized-arraylist-in-java/61956930#comment109586172_61956930):

```
for (int i = 0; i < n + 2; i++) {
    graph.add(new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(n + 2, 0)));
}
```

Comment: i have to take two index

Comment: @DipChakraborty - in that case, you need to initialize the inner list with some values.

Comment: can you help how to do?

Comment: @DipChakraborty - I've updated my answer to fulfil this requirement. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Comment: `new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(n+2, 0))` is a more concise way to "Alternatively, you can initialize".

Comment: Thanks, @AndyTurner for this valuable comment. I've updated my answer to incorporate it so that it becomes more visible to future visitors.

Answer (score 2):

You initialize your ArrayLists with ***capacity*** = `n + 2`, but the ArrayLists are still empty when they are first created. The capacity is different than the size.

**capacity**

The number of elements that could be added to the ArrayList without allocating any additional memory

**size**

The number of elements actually stored in the ArrayList

Your calls to `ArrayList::add` are throwing an out of bounds exception because an empty ArrayList cannot insert a value at index = 3. By definition, the first value that is added to any ArrayList will have index = 0.

Why are you trying to insert values at particular indices? The solution will depend on why you are doing that.

**EDIT: SOLUTION**

When you create the ArrayList, initialize it with `n + 2` entries all with value = 0.

```
...
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> graph = new ArrayList<>(n+2);
for(int i=0; i < n+2 ; i++) {
    ArrayList<Integer> sublist = new ArrayList<>(n+2);
    for (int j = 0; j < n + 2; j++) {
        sublist.add(0);
    }
    graph.add(sublist);
}
...
```

**Keep the rest the same and it will behave as desired.**

Comment: i want to pass graph's vertices, edges and value

Comment: @DipChakraborty see my added solution